# AS3 Fill Color inside line by pen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was trying to make a flash app with AS3 where I can draw line with pen tool with different colors , also fill the shapes on an image with different colors, now I have went through various tutorials and achieved it, however in the end I am faced with 2 problems that I am unable to solve even after 3 days of efforts:

1. How can I fill color inside the shapes formed by using the pen tool,
   say if I draw a rough circle using pen tool and then I try and fill
   it with green, how can I detect `MovieClip`s which I need to fill.
2. When I draw lines over shapes and then try and fill the shapes, the
   shapes gets filled but the lines still appear on top of the shapes
   filled with color.

You can get a better idea of what I have achieved by visiting [this link](http://www.fastswf.com/n3wFTR4), click the pen symbol and paint bucket symbol to see how it works.

Below is my code for pen tool and fill color:

I draw a sprite add an image and then use the property to detect color to draw a line of color I choose, followed by code to fill color where I divide the image in various `MovieClip`s and then make then into one and detect if mouse is clicked on which clip and fill it with selected color.

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


bucbut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nClick0PC);



/////////////pentool code --------
convertToBMD();
pbut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nClick0P);



function nClick0P(event:MouseEvent):void{

spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,boardOut);

spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,boardMove);

spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,boardDown);

spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,boardUp);


}
var spBoard:Sprite=new Sprite(); 

this.addChildAt(spBoard,0);
spBoard.x=20;

spBoard.y=100;
var owl2:owl;
owl2 = new owl();
owl2.name="owl1";
spBoard.addChildAt(owl2,0);
owl2.x=315;

owl2.y=180;


var shDrawing:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
//var shDrawing:Shape=new Shape();
spBoard.addChild(shDrawing);
//spBoard.addChildAt(shDrawing,1);
function nClick0PC(event:MouseEvent):void{

    owl2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,on_owl_click);
}



var doDraw:Boolean=false;

var lineSize:Number=10;

var currentColor:Number;


spBoard.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000);

spBoard.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);

spBoard.graphics.drawRect(0,0,602,330);

spBoard.graphics.endFill();

spBoard.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];







function boardOut(e:MouseEvent):void {

            doDraw=false;

    }


function boardDown(e:MouseEvent):void {

            doDraw=true;

            trace(activeColor);

            shDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(lineSize,activeColor);

            shDrawing.graphics.endFill(); 

            shDrawing.graphics.moveTo(shDrawing.mouseX,shDrawing.mouseY);



    }

function boardUp(e:MouseEvent):void {

            doDraw=false;

    }

function boardMove(e:MouseEvent):void {

            var curX:Number=shDrawing.mouseX;

            var curY:Number=shDrawing.mouseY;


            if(doDraw && checkCoords(curX,curY)){

                shDrawing.graphics.lineTo(curX,curY);

                e.updateAfterEvent();

            }

    }




    function checkCoords(a:Number,b:Number):Boolean {

    if(a>=605-lineSize/2 || a<=lineSize/2 || b>=311-lineSize/2 || b<=lineSize/2){

        return false;
    } 

    else {

        return true;
    }

}



/////////////---------------------color picker
colors.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, chooseColor);
var pixelValue:uint;
        var activeColor:uint = 0x000000;
        var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
var colorsBmd:BitmapData;
        function convertToBMD():void
        {
            colorsBmd = new BitmapData(colors.width,colors.height);
            colorsBmd.draw(colors);
        }


        function chooseColor(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            pixelValue = colorsBmd.getPixel(colors.mouseX,colors.mouseY);
            activeColor = pixelValue;//uint can be RGB!

            ct.color = activeColor;
            //shapeSize.transform.colorTransform = ct;
        }

        ////////////////////========================================Fill color



        function on_owl_click(e:MouseEvent):void {


            for (var i:int = 0; i < owl2.numChildren; i++) {


                if (owl2.getChildAt(i).hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true)) {




                    trace(owl2.getChildAt(i).name);
                                        owl2.getChildAt(i).transform.colorTransform= ct;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I see that an owl it's a `BitmapData`. Fill action it's a `BitmapData.floodfill()` method. So, you need to call `BitmapData.draw()` to add your pen drawings to that BitmapData.

Comment: Hi subdan, actually owl is a movieclip that consists of several movieclips inside of it , so when i click on owl i can detect which movie clip inside it has been clicked and and i can colortransform the movie clip, the problem is , how can i do fill color inside shapes drawn using pen tool and how can i make the filled color appear above the line drawn , in case a line is drawn say over owls face , and i fill color, the line still show , can i fill line in that specific area ...thanks in advance ....

Comment: @subdan , can  you please guide me where i need to make changes, what ever i have coded so far is above only  ..thanks

Comment: Can you provide a FLA file?

Comment: In brief. You need a canvas (Bitmap). On the canvas you draw an owl (BitmapData.copyPixels). Filling action (Paint bucket) it's a floodFill method of BitmapData. Draw action (Pencil) it's a BitmapData.draw method.

Comment: Within several hours I'll give you answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted a lot of your code and left this:

```
convertToBMD();
colors.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, chooseColor);
var activeColor: uint = 0x000000;
var colorsBmd: BitmapData;
function convertToBMD(): void
{
    colorsBmd = new BitmapData(colors.width, colors.height);
    colorsBmd.draw(colors);
}
function chooseColor(e: MouseEvent): void
{
    var pixelValue:uint = colorsBmd.getPixel(colors.mouseX, colors.mouseY);
    activeColor = pixelValue; //uint can be RGB!
}
```

Also I removed an owl at the stage. Download my [FLA](https://mega.co.nz/#!q0sEwL5b!90ebFgNhyxpOWP-HdXHDsaG_5YQvafIXtdLKuQnYFOA) to see changes.

Next. I added two canvases.

```
var canvasData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(650, 437, false, 0xEFEFEF);
var canvas:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvasData);
canvas.x = 0;
canvas.y = 102;
addChild(canvas);

var penCanvas:Shape = new Shape();
penCanvas.x = canvas.x;
penCanvas.y = canvas.y;
```

You can read about Bitmap and BitmapData [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e1b.html).
First canvas it's a raster image. Second canvas it's a Shape, so you can use moveTo and lineTo methods to draw with a pencil.

Next. In library i found an owl image and export it to code.
[image: owl]
If not understand, I can explain more detailed.

Next. Registration event handlers.

```
bucbut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickBucket);
pbut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickPen);

function clickBucket(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, canvasDown);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickOnCanvas);
}

function clickPen(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, canvasDown);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickOnCanvas);
}
```

Let's see at clickOnCanvas method:

```
function clickOnCanvas(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // If we click at the canvas
    if (canvas.hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY))
    {
        canvasData.floodFill(canvas.mouseX, canvas.mouseY,activeColor);
    }
}
```

About floodFill you can read [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#floodFill()).

And the last three methods used to draw by pen.

```
function canvasDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    penCanvas.graphics.lineStyle(10, activeColor);
    penCanvas.graphics.moveTo(penCanvas.mouseX, penCanvas.mouseY);

    // only when mouse button is down we register two handlers, one for move and another for mouse up
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
}

function mouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // when mouse is moving we are drawing line
    penCanvas.graphics.lineTo(penCanvas.mouseX, penCanvas.mouseY);
    // As I said earlier canvasData it's a raster image. So we copy penCanvas and paste to canvasData.
    canvasData.draw(penCanvas);

    // For a smoother drawing
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function mouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
}
```

That's all!

[Here](https://mega.co.nz/#!q0sEwL5b!90ebFgNhyxpOWP-HdXHDsaG_5YQvafIXtdLKuQnYFOA) you can download sources.

Comment: Hi subdan thanks a ton for this help , can you please check the fla link again and the sources link, i tried to download it and it does not work, i am trying to use your code now and making changes , if i can get the fla may be i can see where i am wrong ....Once again thanks a lot ...

Comment: @multiverse, you should add this code `canvasData.copyPixels(owlData,new Rectangle(0,0,owlData.width,owlData.height), new Point(150, 60));` after `canvasData.draw(penCanvas);`. This is a 96 line. If you want I can explain why I made it.

Comment: @multiverse Add `penCanvas.graphics.clear();` in `mouseUp` function.

Comment: This occurs due to the smoothing. `floodFill` will fill only one color. Drawn line has several shades. See http://subdan.ru/work/12.png Only black color will be filled. Grey color didn't be filled. I can't help you with this.

Comment: I advice you to use [this library](http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/). There's no such problem. I always use it.

Comment: @subdan, is there a way i can use  only the fill color option from this library and also the line draw as it is more smooth and keep every  thing same, there is more then 1000 line of code and i am struggling to understand ... thanks again ...

Comment: @multiverse You don't need to understand the code of the library. Learn API. It's easy. I used this library in your project. See code http://subdan.ru/work/Archive.zip

Comment: @multiverse I don't understand your request. Delete FLA from my web-site?

Comment: @multiverse I deleted all your files from my web-site.